# What atmospheric conditions would prevent sound from traveling more than a short distance?

Tags: atmosphere, chemistry

My story has an alien planet with an oxygen-based atmosphere about twice as dense as Earth’s. When on the planet, sound attenuation is much more rapid, so much that any noise more than fifty feet away would be completely inaudible. As a result, someone on the planet can see much further than they can hear.

Is there a way I can make this more feasible by tinkering with the composition of my planet’s atmosphere?

Edit: here are some parameters I’d like to shoot for.

- Minimal fog: some is OK but visibility should be relatively clear for long distances.
- Colder temperatures would be ideal (I.e. -10 to 10 degrees Celsius)
- Atmospheric pressure between 1-2 atm

Comment: Fog isn't particularly efficient at absorbing sound. Especially across a wide range of frequency, some sounds being more absorbed than others. It is more a distorting feature than absorbing. Certainly 50 feet of fog won't completely absorb sound.

Comment: Would some sort of white noise source be useful? Millions of librarians going "shhhhh!" Drowning out sound rather than absorbing it.

Comment: very very low pressure, like far lower than humans could breath or fire would work. other than that magic.

Comment: @BobaFit ideally the effect would be complete silence. But maybe if the sound drowning it out is a very high or low frequency (I.e. edge of hearing spectrum)? Not sure if that would work.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can't do much about sound propagation using physics or chemistry. Use physiology instead.

Atmosphere density modification wouldn't work. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound):
At a constant temperature, the gas pressure has no effect on the speed of sound, since the density will increase, and since pressure and density (also proportional to pressure) have equal but opposite effects on the speed of sound, and the two contributions cancel out exactly.

Temperature and humidity have minor effect on speed of sound, within few percents.

Sound propagates faster in low molecular weight gases, e.g. it is about 4 times faster in hydrogen. It doesn't give you much though unless you want dichlorodifluoromethane to be a big part of atmosphere. And even then it would be only twice as slow.

Fortunately, sound is not just a physical phenomenon, there is physiology involved. People with hearing problems do exist in completely normal atmosphere.

Local population "just evolved this way" may work depending on settings but good sound perception gives huge and clear evolutionary benefits, so it generally doesn't look plausible.

Partial loss of hearing is much more believable. Depending on settings it can be a curse, virus pandemic that affected DNA of the whole population, result of genetic experiments, side effect of WMD, etc.

Comment: Could physiology affect sound by distance? Ideally, the people on this planet can hear fine within a few feet of a sound, but faraway sounds are nonexistent.

Comment: @Mark Price There are very little limitations to weirdness of alien physiology. Let's say they had an ability to filter out remote noise sources at will to improve perception and location of weaker but more important sounds closer to them. It would require a third sound sensitive organ of some sort. Not necessarily a complete ear, just enough to make basic triangulation work (as opposed to our ability to discern direction only). Due to the new affliction this filtering is now always on.

Answer (score 4):

### constant thunderstorm

There are constant thunderstorms raging,  and the thunder rolls over the place like waves. Against the noise, anything said is drowned out.

Answer (score 2):

### Sound absorbing particles

In your atmosphere there are handwavium particles very common. These particles are very small and do not interact with the lungs of mammals at all. We breath them in, we breath them out. Also they have the exact same density as air so they neither settle down nor float upwards.

However these particles do have a very curious property. They pick up energy from vibrations in the ranges between 16 Hz and 20 kHz (hearable frequencies) and convert them into heat.

These particle where brought to the earth by a massive meteorite.
Depending on your setting and if you want to handle the implications for evolution and society the meteroite fell down

- hundrets of millions of years ago -> evolution would not favour hearing organs so much, maybe other senses would develop in the fauna
- when humankind was still young and nomadic -> to short of a timeframe for evolution to care much but big impact on societies
- a few decades ago -> no impact on evolution and little impact on society, but scientists would be working furiously on removing/filtering the particle out of the atmosphere to restore our hearing capabilities.

Funny thought: They could also be produced by a plant and may be seasonal like pollen

Answer (score 0):

Would it be enough if the sound propagated only in one direction?

Small mountains and faster rotation, the atmosphere would be affected by constant strong winds. The winds would affect sound propagation, it will be very difficult to hear what is happening five metres downwind.